# Views Will Not Load In CI HMVC When Add An Array

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-hmvc

My views will not load in multiple sub-folders when I add a array class. I am trying to make a custom controller class so can load controller with in controller in codeigniter.

When I load the array/variable the view only works on first level. Does not pick up when ad two or more sub-folders. Need it to be able to pick up multiple folders when I add controller as an array.

**MY_Loader.php**

```
  public function controller($uri, $params = array(), $return = FALSE) {
   // No valid module detected, add current module to uri
      list($module) = $this->detect_module($uri);
      if (!isset($module)) {
            $router = & $this->_ci_get_component('router');
      if ($router->module) {
         $module = $router->module;
         $uri = $module . '/' . $uri;
      }
   }

   // Add module
   $this->add_module($module);

   // Execute the controller method and capture output
   $void = $this->_load_controller($uri, $params, $return);

   // Remove module
   $this->remove_module();

   return $void;
}

public function view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE) {
        // Detect module
        if (list($module, $class) = $this->detect_module($view)) {
            // Module already loaded
            if (in_array($module, $this->_ci_modules)) {
                return parent::view($class, $vars, $return);
            }

            // Add module
            $this->add_module($module);

            // Let parent do the heavy work
            $void = parent::view($class, $vars, $return);

            // Remove module
            $this->remove_module();

            return $void;
        } else {
            return parent::view($view, $vars, $return);
        }
    }
```

Controller HMVC.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();     
}

public function index() {
    $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('admin/common/header');
    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data); Work
    $this->load->view('templates/welcome_message', $data); Not Work
    $this->load->view('templates/common/welcome_message', $data)//Not Work   
}
```

Comment: Your controller should extends MX_Controller I guess.

Comment: I have different hmvc https://github.com/jenssegers/CodeIgniter-HMVC-Modules this one here loads CI rather than mx